# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой TemplateDoesNotExist at / account / login / 
bookmarks - проект
account - приложение
views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

bookmarks/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls'))
]
```

account/urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

login.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `login.html` где лежит?

Comment: @Александр F:\python\env\bookmarks\account\tempaltes\account

Answer (score 0):

Проверь добавил ли ты `account` в `INSTALLED_APPS` в `settings.py`